# How to get beep to work in R macOS Monterey?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using macOS Monterey on Apple Silicon and found that beer::beep() does not work.

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
MacOS 12.3. Monterey
```

I've updated installed packages but beepr was not in the list of packages needing updating.  The speakers on my macBook work.

Answer (score 0):

I de-installed the package *beepr* and then re-installed it; it makes  a satisfyingly annoying beep.